# HTTP response is 404 rather than 401 with authorization.json Am I missing something?

Tags: azure, authentication, webforms, asp.net-web-api2, azure-web-app-service

Posted this in Azure App Service Forums and got no response so...

Framework is 4.7.1

Application is ASP.Net web form with two Web API controllers.
Web site and HealthCheck controller should allow anonymous requests.
The other controller should be authenticated with Azure Active Directory using a certificate as credentials.

Authentication in the App Service is set to

- Allow Anonymous requests (no action)
- The Authentication Provider is set to Azure Active Directory
- The Management mode is set to Express
- A certificate has been added to the Management Application

Only issue is that when an anonymous request hits the secured controller a HTTP 404 rather than a 401 is returned.

If an authenticated request is made a HTTP 200 is returned.
Am I missing some configuration setting?

Here is the route map in Global.asax.cs in Application_Start

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Here is the authorization.json file

```
{
  "routes": [{
      "path_prefix": "/",
      "policies": { "unauthenticated_action": "AllowAnonymous" }
    },
    {
      "path_prefix": "/api",
      "policies": { "unauthenticated_action": "RejectWith401" }
    },
    {
      "http_methods": [ "GET"],
      "path_prefix": "/api/HealthCheck",
      "policies": { "unauthenticated_action": "AllowAnonymous" }
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There must be an issue with your file authorization.json. Are there any subdirectories other than this `/api` ? Try adding them too, with `/api/(*whatever path*)` in your `path_prefix`.

Comment: This is Web.API within a ASP.Net web form application.  There is NO API folder there are only controllers that handle the route. I have already tried to modify the authorization.json to indicate what the response should be on every controller and the results are the same.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that forms authentication redirect senses the 401 and tried to redirect to a login page that was not specified correctly in the loginUrl attribute of the forms element.  This code in the Application_BeginRequest of the global.aspx.cs file fixes my issues

```
            var context = new HttpContextWrapper(Context);
        // set flag only if forms auth enabled and request comes from ajax
        if (FormsAuthentication.IsEnabled && context.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.StartsWith("/api",StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            context.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
        }
```

Turning on Verbose logging in Azure (suggested by Microsoft) indicated that the authenticaton was returning a 401.  At that point I knew a redirect was occurring and that it was probably forms authentication.  This link also helped me figure out the fix

https://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/04/prevent-forms-authentication-login-page-redirect-when-you-donrsquot-want.aspx/